# Delete elements in a std::vector<std::string> which matches with the characters in another given std::string

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector, stdstring, std

How can I remove elements in the vector `alphabets` which matches with any of the characters in the string `plaintext`?

Here's my attempt:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   //init
   std::vector<std::string> alphabets{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
   //input
   std::string plaintext;
   std::cout << "enter plain text: ";
   std::cin >> plaintext;

   for (std::string::iterator it = plaintext.begin(); it != plaintext.end(); it++)
   {
      std::vector<std::string>::iterator toErase;
      toErase = std::find(alphabets.begin(), alphabets.end(), *it);
      if (toErase != alphabets.end())
      {
         alphabets.erase(toErase);
      }
   }
}
```

When I tried to compile it. But I got this error:

```
17: note:   'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' is not derived from
'const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>' { return *__it == _M_value; }
...

203 : 5 : note : candidate : 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool 
std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
   std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)'
   operator==(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits> & __a,
      ...
```

Comment: because the second string(alphabets) is fixed which I later need it to construct a matrix form which would be easier if it's a vector

Comment: A single character, like `'a'`, is not the same thing as a string with only one character, like `"a"`. You can't compare them.

Comment: I need to convert it into 2d vector later where I need to make some transpose kinda operations, so I just thought vector would be easy to manipulate. BTW, thank you, I would try with the string.

Comment: std::vector will simply provide you with 2/3 unnecessary extra functions. But that is bad programming. Use the things made to do the things you wanna do...

Comment: Even if it is already answered, I'm marking this question as _needs clarity_, as the title and the body of the question describe two totally different intents.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I made some changes to my question, is that clear now, and any suggestions?

Comment: @BalaGanesh, I've made more changes, however the question can be still improved; for instance, since the question is not about IO, you can remove the `//input` part and just put `std::string plaintext{"abcdefghijklmnopqrst"};`, so you can tell you expect the modified `alphabets` to contain only `{"u","v","w","x","y","z"}`.

Comment: @BalaGanesh, however, now I've update my c++20 solution too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `*it` has a type of `char` not `std::string`. This is what the compiler complaining about. Therefore you need to pass a `std::string` to the [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as follows.

```
auto toErase = std::find(alphabets.begin(), alphabets.end(), std::string{ *it });
 //                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is [a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zjMfnW).

---

Also, note the followings:

- You can change the  `std::vector<std::string> alphabets` to a
  `std::vector<char> alphabets` or even a single `std::string` as your
  `alphabets` containes/ represents `char`s as strings. In the case of `std::string`s (i.e. `alphabets`), the [`std::basic_string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)
  is more appropriate to use, rather than having more general `std::find` at first place.
- For vector erase, you could use [erase–remove
  idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), or
  since C++20, using non-member function of `std::vector` itself, so
  called
  [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2).

Answer (score 4):

In

```
std::find(alphabets.begin(), alphabets.end(), *it);
```

`alphabets.begin()` and `alphabets.end()` are `std::vector` of `std::string`s iterators, but `it` is a `std::string` iterator, it iterates over characters, these arguments are incompatible, the can't be used together in `std::find` without some kind of conversion.

That said a better way to correct your code would be to turn your `alphabets` container, which is overly complicated, from `std::vector<std::string>` into a simple `std::string`.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N6mP44iXxLSgWw0X)

```
//init
std::string alphabets{"abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}; //<--- simple string

//input
std::string plaintext;
std::cout << "enter plain text: ";
std::cin >> plaintext;

for (std::string::iterator it = plaintext.begin(); it != plaintext.end(); it++)
{
    std::string::iterator toErase; //<--- string iterator
    /*or auto */ toErase = std::find(alphabets.begin(), alphabets.end(), *it);
    if (toErase != alphabets.end())
    {
        alphabets.erase(toErase);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I understood:
You have a string say `str1`. Now you've been given another string say, `str2`. Now you want to delete all characters from `str1`, which are present in `str2`.

In that case, I suggest scanning the input as a string instead of vector, and then using the `delete` loop

```
for(auto it = str1.begin(); it != str1.end(); it++) {
    if(str2.find(std::string{*it}) != std::string::npos) {
        it = str1.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A C++20 oneliner solution.

It focuses more on *what* you  want to do (it uses [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) because we want to erase elements based on a condition, and it uses [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to check that condition), rather than *how* you do it (there are no `for` loops indeed.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // inputs
    // I don't like this alphabet; a std::vector<char> would have been much better
    // and it would allow to remove the ugly [0] in the std::find below
    std::vector<std::string> alphabet{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
    std::string plaintext{"abcdefghijklmnopq"};


    // the solution is a oneliner
    std::erase_if(alphabet, [&plaintext](auto x){
        return !(std::find(std::begin(plaintext), std::end(plaintext), x[0]) == std::end(plaintext));
    });

    // output to verify the correct result
    for (auto& e : alphabet) { // prints r s t u v w x y z
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the suggestion about the lambda is useful, as the lambda is used immediately, so there are no lifetime issues to be concerned with, I'll put it in in a moment.